# Spring Cloud Config File System Search Locations-Having Application name specific folders

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have around 10 applications and I am storing all the property files in one location on the file system. So suppose for example- All my property files are inside C:/Config.
Now what i want to do is have an application named folder structure. So lets say I have 3 applications named A,B and C. Then a folder structure like-

```
               C:
                -Config
                  -A
                   -env1(profile)
                     -A-env1.yaml
                   -env2
                     -A-env2.yml
                  -B
                   -env1
                      -B-env1.yml
                   -env2
                      -B-env2.yml
                  -C
                    -env1
                      -C-env1.yml
                    -env2
                      -C-env2.yml
```

Is this possible to achieve? I have gone through the documentation and have tried few things like adding the following in search Locations-

```
             file:///C:/Config/${application}/${profile}
             file://C:/Config/${label} (label tag which is there by default)
```

This doesn't work though.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Better to have environment folders and project specific inside as projects might keep changing. Environments wont change frequently in long run

Answer (score -1):

You can load application properties from arbitrary file-system location.

By default Spring reads the following directories (taken from [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)):

1)A /config subdirectory of the current directory

2)The current directory

3)A classpath /config package

4)The classpath root

You can also refer to an explicit location using the `spring.config.location` environment property (comma-separated list of directory locations, or file paths).

Example:

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```

Comment: Thank u for ur reply. But this doesnt address my question.

Comment: You can have the desired directory structure and you can load configuration files on start up with the approach described above.